# How can I select specific elements from an XML using Linq to Xml?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I pick out the Fields from the following XML using LINQ:

```
<MESSAGE MSGID="123" NAME="MyMessage">
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD NAME="F1" FTYPE="STRING">123</FIELD>
    <FIELD NAME="F2"> FTYPE="INT">0</FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</MESSAGE>
```

Code:

```
XDocument xmldoc = null;

try
{
    xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(bstrXml);

    //Returns NULL
    //var result = xmldoc.Descendants("Fields");
    //Returns NULL
    //var result = xmldoc.Elements("Fields");
}
```

Comment: Is Fields a tag? Or an attribute? If it's an attribute, you need to call `Attribute("Fields")` on the corresponding `XElement`. Show us what that portion of the XML looks like.

Comment: Hint. Fields != FIELDS.

Comment: `Descendants("FIELDS")` should work.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Elements with attribute Fields can be found using

```
var childElements = xDoc.Elements();
var fieldAttributes = childElements.Elements().Select(p => p.Attribute("Fields"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will search for xml field elements and select a field by name

```
        var fieldName = "F1";
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
        var field = xDoc.Descendants("FIELD")
            .Where(f => string.Compare(f.Attribute("NAME").Value, fieldName, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) == 0);
```

Change the where expression to refine your search.